# How to shift 2 bytes 3 positions in Python?

Tags: python, byte, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I've run a 5v signal from a throttle position sensor to the "User 3" input on this wide band module.  It has a RS232 interface which logs data.  So far I've been able to identify the frame headers and which bytes correspond to "User 3".  I've also verified that these bytes increase as the throttle is opened.
https://www.wbo2.com/sw/logger.htm

Relevant documentation

> Bytes 10 through 15 are the three 0 to 5.00 Volt user inputs U1, U2 &
> U3 (there's an additional user input available on version 2.0 compared
> to 1.5). Although these inputs are sampled just once, they are shifted
> to be in the range 0 to 8184 (ie. 1024 steps - 0, 8, 16 .. 8176, 8184)
> for version 1.5 compatibility.
>
> On the 2.0 unit there is just one 10 bit sample for each channel, but
> the result is shifted 3 places to be compatible with the 1.5 data.
> (ie. there are 1024 steps - 0, 8, 16 .. 8176, 8184) for version 1.5
> compatibility.

I don't understand how to convert the bytes to volts.  Examples

- throttle closed '\x03\xd8' (~0.67v)
- throttle open   '\x1c\x18' (~4.65v)

Comment: Oh, I was reading it wrong. It sends a 13-bit value even though there is only a 10-bit value from the source. That explains why the lowest nibble is 0bX000 (lower 3 bits are always zero) and the high nibble be 0/1 only. So there is no shifting required as it’s already normalized.

Comment: Just convert the bytes to an integer, v (`high << 8 + low`) and then `5.0 * (v / 8192)` - assuming a simple linear correlation. Note that that v has the range 0..8192.

Comment: Where did you get those examples?  They don't seem to jibe with the description.  I get 0.601v and 4.394v

Comment: @user2864740 Can you try doing the math on that conversion?  I tried it with both 8184 and 8192 as corresponding to 5.0v, and neither one gives a reliable result.

Comment: Thanks!  This looks roughly right.  `int.from_bytes(low, 'big') / 8192 * 5` & `int.from_bytes(high, 'big') / 8192 * 5`

Comment: @Prune Your values are correct. The calculated results are close-ish, not exact. And not linear. I did not see any reference values.

Comment: @user2864740  Those results aren't "close" enough for me to have any confidence; that's why I asked for a math check.  0.601 is not "close" to 0.67; it's off by more than 10% far beyond the precision implied.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a simple linear transformation of the range [0,8184] to [0.0,5.0]

That would make the conversion equation

```
voltage = hex_in / 8184 * 5.0
```

Where hex_in is the integer formed by those two bytes.  Unfortunately, the arithmetic doesn't correspond to  your examples:

```
>>> 0x3d8 / 8192 * 5.0
0.6005859375
>>> 0x3d8 / 8184 * 5.0
0.6011730205278593

>>> 0x1c18 / 8184 * 5.0
4.393939393939394
```

If your examples are faulty, perhaps we have a solution.  If they're accurate, then we need a full description of the value encoding.

Comment: I'm gonna guess that 8192 is correct based on this example for converting the lambda16 to air fuel ratio. https://www.wbo2.com/sw/lambda-16.htm  There may be something else going on the electrical side because I had a labjack DAQ logging this voltage signal earlier and it was lower than what my multi meter is reading.  As for the value encoding that first link is the best documentation I've found so far about decoding the frames.